# Problems with matplotlib and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the observed and calculated values of a time series parameter using `matplotlib`.  The observed data are stored in an XL file which I read using `openpyxl` and convert to a `pandas dataframe`.  The simulated values are read as elapsed days which I convert to `numpy datetime` using

```
delt = get_simulated_time()               
t0 = np.datetime64('2004-01-01T00:00:00')
tsim = t0 + np.asarray(delt).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

I plot the data using the following code snippet

```
df = obs_data_df.query("block=='blk-7'")
pobs = df['pres']
tobs = df['date'] 
tobs = np.array(tobs, dtype='datetime64')
print(type(tobs), np.min(tobs), np.max(tobs))
axs.plot(tobs, pobs, '.', color='g', label='blk-7, obs', markersize=8)

tsim = np.array(curr_sim_obj.tsim, dtype='datetime64')
print(type(tsim), np.min(tsim), np.max(tsim))
axs.plot(tsim, curr_sim_obj.psim[:, 0], '-', color='g', label='blk-7, sim', linewidth=1)
```

The results of the print statements are:

```
print(type(tobs), np.min(tobs), np.max(tobs))
... <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 2004-06-01T00:00:00.000000000 2020-06-01T00:00:00.000000000
print(type(tsim), np.min(tsim), np.max(tsim))
... <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 2004-01-01T00:00:00 2020-07-20T00:00:00
```

These types look OK but I get this error message from matplotlib:
`ValueError: view limit minimum -36907.706903627106 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units`
I don't understand why I am getting this message since the print statements indicate that the data are consistent.  I tried investigating further using

```
print(np.dtype(tsim), np.min(tobs), np.max(tobs))
```

but get this error message:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

This has confused me even further since I set the `tobs` data type in the preceding statement.  I have to say that I am really confused about the differences in the way that python, pandas and numpy handle dates and the various code kludges above reflect workarounds that I have picked up along the way.  I would basically like to know how to plot the two different time series on the same plot so all suggestions very welcome.  Thank you in advance!

**Update:**
While cutting down the code to get a simpler case that reproduced the error I found the following code buried in the plotting routine:
`axs.plot(10*np.random.randn(100), 10*np.random.randn(100), 'o')`
This was left over from testing the plot routine.  Once I removed this the errors disappeared.  I guess I need to check my code more carefully ...

Comment: Your example is not reproducible in case you were wondering about the downvotes. If the date is in a pandas dataframe, why don't you convert it to a datetime object? This is even supported by pandas csv readers but be careful with implicit date format assumptions. More information on matplotlib's datetime format can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html

Comment: Hi Mr T - was wondering why the question had been down-voted ... your suggestion to use the matplotlib date routines solved the problem - I used the num2date function and things plot as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad this is solved.

Comment: Bugs like this are why folks are asked to produce minimal examples.  Usually you fidn the solution yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the [`matplotlib.dates.num2date`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) function on both sets of data.

Comment: This isn’t a very helpful answer.   How could this possibly have fixed the issue.  Fwiw matplotlib can easily plot numpy datetime64 so it’s unclear what issue you were originally having.

Comment: I have no idea how this could have fixed the issue ... but it did!  If I have time I will try to reproduce the error using a simplified version of the Python script

Comment: Explanation for apparent issue given in updated post